# Without any external files, how can the ToolBoxBitmap icon be set from a c# class?

Tags: c#, vb.net, bitmap, toolbox

As someone who has used many language IDE's over the years, this seems to be a gap in functionality as Visual Studio 6 allowed for embedding the 'icon' of a custom usercontrol directly into that control without the requirement to distribute any additional files with the project.

Is there anyway for me to use an image created in code as the toolbox icon.  Can be either a base64 encoded image stored as a string and decoded or using the Graphics api to create a new bitmap and set it.  I am aware of the option to load an icon from another existing file.

Current example of how an icon is loaded into the toolbox is as follows :

```
[ToolboxBitmap( typeof( Resfinder ), "MyControl.bmp" )]
public partial class MyControl: UserControl {

}
```

Just to clarify further what I am looking for specifically :

In previous IDE versions, the image to be used as the toolbox icon could be embedded DIRECTLY into the control itself without any requirements for any other files than the control file, and control form layout file, requiring only the following :

- The control file
- The control form layout file

In the current version of the IDE, common way to do this is at minimum :

- A resource mapper
- The control file
- The control form layout file
- The icon in bitmap format.
- The project file (required to detail how all the above stuff goes together, else, they are just a bunch of files)

**BEFORE** ( IDE's prior to .NET )

[image]
[image]

Source Distribution:  2 files in the same folder.
Project file required:  No

**AFTER** ( .NET based IDE's )

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/311315

Source Distribution:  7-10 files in various folders including project file.

Project file required:  Yes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can you not add the image to your project and set its build action to "Embedded Resource"?  You would then not need to deploy the image file separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add the image file as a background image to your control.
2. Go to the Control's resx file and choose Open With | Xml (Text)
3. Copy the entire the `<data>` node for the added image.
4. Add the image file as a Resources.resx image.
5. Open Resources.resx using Open With | Xml (Text).
6. Replace the data node with the data node from the Control.
7. Change the name attribute to something else.
8. Now use ToolboxBitmap to call the resource.
9. Clean up - remove the background image.